# Multiple outgoing ipv6 addresses

Tags: c, linux, proxy, ipv6

I need to implement the following scheme (in C, however the language is not the case here):

client(192.168.1.2) <-> proxy(addr4: 192.168.1.1:1000, addr6: FE80:0000:0000:0000:0202:B3FF:FE1E:8329) <-> some_remote_host(remote_addr6)

The thing is **addr6** on **proxy** side must be dynamically changed according to incoming ipv4 port. For example:

- client connects to 192.168.1.1:**1000**, outgoing connection is made via **addr6_0**
- client connects to 192.168.1.1:**1001**, outgoing connection is made via **addr6_1**
- etc ...

The most straight-forward implementation would be: assign multiple static ipv6 addrs to ethernet interface and use *bind()* on socket before outgoing connection. The problem is that the number of incoming ports/outgoing addrs can be ~10000 (and as far as I understood recommended value for net.ipv6.conf.all.max_addresses is 32 or 64, default is 16).

The questions are:

- What possible problems can I expect if I assign 10000 ipv6 addrs to one interface, I assume performance issues?
- Is there a better way to achieve the goal?

Comment: Why can't you have a single IPv6 address with different ports like you do with IPv4? Also, the FE80::/10 network is a link-local network, so if the target host truly is remote, it will never work.

Comment: FE80 was just a copy-paste as an example, you're right.
I can't have single ipv6 addr as the whole idea is to access external resources from different ipv6 addrs. That's the requirement of the customer (a one-time freelance job), I don't know the real purpose of the scheme.

Comment: The documentation/example network for IPv6 is 2001:db8::/32.